# Random number-type script keeps giving same results

Tags: vbscript

I can't figure out where I made a mistake. Making a script for a risk-style forum game, keeps not working.

```
intHighNumber = 10000

intLowNumber = 1

intNumbers = 1

For i = 1 To intNumbers

    Randomize

    intNumber = Int((intHighNumber - intLowNumber + 1) * Rnd + intLowNumber)

    strnum = strnum& "   " & CStr(intNumber)

Next
If strnum=0000 Or 1111 Or 2222 Or 3333 Or 4444 Or 5555 Or 6666 Or 7777 Or 8888 Or 9999 Or 1234 Or 2345 Or 3456 Or 4567 Or 5678 Or 6789 Then
x = MsgBox(100)
ElseIf strnum=123 Or 234 Or 345 Or 456 Or 567 Or 678 Or 789 Or 1123 Or 1345 Or 1456 Or 1567 Or 1678 Or 1789 Or 2123 Or 2234 Or 2456 Or 2567 Or 2678 Or 2789 Or 3123 Or 3234 Or 3345 Or 3567 Or 3678 Or 3789 Or 4123 Or 4234 Or 4345 Or 4456 Or 4678 Or 4789 Or 5123 Or 5234 Or 5345 Or 5456 Or 5567 Or 5789 Or 6123 Or 6234 Or 6345 Or 6456 Or 6567 Or 6678 Or 7123 Or 7234 Or 7345 Or 7456 Or 7567 Or 7678 Or 7789 Or 8123 Or 8234 Or 8345 Or 8456 Or 8567 Or 8678 Or 8789 Or 9123 Or 9234 Or 9345 Or 9456 Or 9567 Or 9678 Or 9789 Then
x = MsgBox(50)
Else 
x = MsgBox(3)
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `If` is bad; see my answer to your other/same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21050952/603855). In addition: Concatenatiing the numbers in the loop and comparing single numbers against the string after the loop is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have declared (dim) your variables, I still see a couple of issues:

strnum& should be strnum &

But mostly, I don't see how your "if" statement could work as you are comparing a string variable to list of integer values, and the string variable has multiple (according to the number of players) blocks of digits.

I cannot reproduce the "expected then" error, but I believe you need to rewrite your "If" statement.

Comment: It used to give me a expected then anymore, but I am getting the same number every time (100). I might make it repeat having x defined and written to a .txt for intNumbers times.

Also, I didn't know about the dim thing. thanks!

Comment: You are getting the same message box because your "IF" statement cannot possibly work as you would like it too.  See some of the other posts here too, you are comparing a String value to an Integer value.  The most likely scenario, if your "IF" statement was working, would be for you to get the msgbox(3).

If you are just starting out learning a language, I would take the advice of some other posters here and learn a more modern one.  VB.Net, c#.net, python, etc.  Not only are you likely to get more assistance, the knowledge you gain will be more of an asset to you.

Answer (score 0):

The expression in your if statement is probably not what you want. It should be something like

```
If (strnum=0) Or (strnum=1111) Or (strnum=2222) ... Then
```

You should be aware of the switch statement:

```
Select Case strOption
  Case 0, 1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666, 7777, 8888, 9999, 1234, 2345, 3456, 4567, 5678, 6789
    MsgBox(100)
  Case 123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678, 789, 1123, 1345, 1456, 1567, 1678, 1789, 2123, 2234, 2456, 2567, 2678, 2789, 3123, 3234, 3345, 3567, 3678, 3789, 4123, 4234, 4345, 4456, 4678, 4789, 5123, 5234, 5345, 5456, 5567, 5789, 6123, 6234, 6345, 6456, 6567, 6678, 7123, 7234, 7345, 7456, 7567, 7678, 7789, 8123, 8234, 8345, 8456, 8567, 8678, 8789, 9123, 9234, 9345, 9456, 9567, 9678, 9789
    MsgBox(50)
  Case Else
    MsgBox(3)
End Select
```

Which is still pretty ugly and unmaintainable though.

This is not part of your question, but you might want to check out more modern languages such as vb.net (since you're into vb) or Python. [Here are some reasons](http://web.archive.org/web/20061029012347/http://adamv.com/dev/articles/hatevbs/vbscript) why vbscript simply isn't fun, since you seem to be doing this for fun.